# How to create an embedded database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

So, I started to make an app on my main pc. The database works just fine.

But when I move the app on the second Pc,or any other Pc , to continue the work, it chrases, and throws this exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Cristi\OneDrive\Documente\Licurici\Licurici\qst.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'
```

This is the initial connection string :

```
SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cristi\OneDrive\Documente\Licurici\Licurici\qst.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

I changed the connection string in:

```
 SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|qst.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

and  I also tried this :

```
 SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.qstConnectionString);
```

The last 2 strings work fine, and makes the database portable, but makes INSERT commands not work anymore, at all. This is my sql command:

```
sqc.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Question(quest, a, b, c, d) VALUES(@q, @a, @b, @c, @d)",sqc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", richTextBox1.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", richTextBox2.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", richTextBox3.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", richTextBox4.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", richTextBox5.Text.ToString());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqc.Close();
```

So  I am asking you, how do I create a portable(or embedded) database, that will work on any pc, without having to change manually the connection string everytime  and also have the possibility to work properly with the sqlcommands like insert  ?

I'm working in Visual Studio 2017 with .NET framework.The project is a windows form app.

Any help is appreciated ! :)

Comment: There are too many possible answers here. I would say use services for all your data work and put the database on a centralized server. But there are dozens of other options. As such this is not a well enough focused question.

Comment: When you say it does not work anymore, it does not do anything or you get an exception?

Comment: I haven't used it-- but surely you'll get recommendations for SQLite. It seems to be the most commonly used embedded db. I assume if you're looking for an embedded db you don't need your users to share data?

Comment: The insert command doesn't insert new data into the table .  I just need a way to make the database portable...